# QTP command repository dependancy

Tags: automated-tests, add-in, qtp

When open the HP **Quick Test Professional** we gets **Add-in Manager** window for select add-ins we wants,

By selecting a Add-in from that menu, is it only effect for ***identify objects*** from the window we try to automate or Is that commands(Click, DoubleClick, etc.) also arrange according to the above selection?

eg- By only selecting **WEB** add-in from the manager and Try to Scroll the browser pane up

```
window("abc").Scrollup
```

but only selecting **Java** add-in from the manager, I dont able to find that Scrollup,

Is that commands depend on what we **selected add-in from the Add-in Manager** or Is it a **QTP commands**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really clear what you are asking.

`Click` is a test object´s method.

The object repository (OR) contains test objects, or at least info that allows QTP to create (instantiate) test objects when you reference them using `TestobjectClass ("TOName")`.

During recording, QTP creates playback statements (calls to test object methods) that reference test objects in the OR, and creates those test objects there.

What kind (class) of test object it creates indeed is determined by the currently active add-ins.

For example, if you record a Java application, but deactivate the Java add-in, you won´t see Java objects in your OR after recording.

That means .Click calls might still be recorded, but for lower-level objects, like `Window`.

The layout in the OR is just the parent/child relationship (in a simplified way, since in the OR, there usually are less hierarchy levels than in the GUI -- a listbox in a groupbox in a groupbox in a Tab in a frame in a dialog is stored as a listbox in a dialog).

Comment: is that Command repository (Click, Scroll) are depend on Add-in Selection?

eg- when I select only WEB from Add-in selection, I'll get
    browser("abc").object("btnxyz").Click
    browser("abc").object("btnxyz").scrollup

If I select java I dont get scroll

So is there has a dependancy for commands (Click, Type, Scroll, etc)

Comment: Well only insofar as the add-ins determine what method call will be recorded. If there is no add-in active recognizing the control, the default functionality will record stuff that is more low-level.

Comment: You can, however, have those calls and those test objects in the OR even if they were created with an add-in active that currently is inactive. (I do not know what you mean with "command repository". There is an object repository (OR), and the test with its actions scripts which can contain the "commands" (which are method calls).)